# 4 cycles in undirected graph

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, cycle

I have an undirected graph which is given as a neighbourship matrix. I need to find the count of 4 cycles: the cycles which contain 4 edges. If you have any idea about the algorithm, please help me.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. To make it easier for us to answer your question, it would help if you provided some more information. What have you tried? What error did you get? Can you provide a short, self-contained example of the problem you are seeing? See http://sscce.org, http://whathaveyoutried.com, and http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for details on how to write a good question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have tried to count using 3 loops but it takes long. I need more optimal solution for this. In future I will take in case your comments about writing question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple (not optimal) approach pseudo code:

```
output = []
skip_nodes = []
for node in input_graph:
    if node in skip_nodes:
        continue
    for path in deep_search(start=node, max_depth=4):
        if len(path) == 4 and path[1] == path[4]:
            output.append(path)
            skip_nodes.append(path[2], path[3], path[4])
return output
```

Comment: Michal, but there will be duplicates in this case, yes?

Comment: @user1982807: you are correct. It's easy to fix it.

Comment: do you think dividing by 4 will give the correct result? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @user1982807: I think so. However, It might not be faster. It depends How big and dense is the graph.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply the matrix by itself 4 times, as far as I remember the non-0 diagonal items would participate in 4-edge cycles (might have the wrong criteria here but you can dig further)

http://www.math.vt.edu/people/brown/doc/cycles_dm9875.pdf

Comment: Thank you, I think this is very nice solution to my problem. Let me investigate this and see if it will be optimal.

Comment: If you find an optimized matrix library that supports sparse matrices you can get this to work fast. Matrix multiplication boils down to recursion if it's treated as a table of numbers. Also - your graph is undirected so your matrix will be symmetrical. This can also be used to optimize the multiplication

Comment: I have to not use the sparse matrix. But thanks for idea.